# Dlink DWA -111 USB Wifi card on Ubuntu 12.10 in Vmware workstation

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, vmware, ndiswrapper

I am trying to make my Dlink DWA-111 work on Ubuntu 12.10 in vmware workstation. since Vmware doesn't recognize my integrated wifi card as a wifi card, I changed to a USB one. This one is recognized in windows 8, but when I launch my Ubuntu VM, it doesn't work at all. I'm still getting connected.

Disabling the USBb from the host and activating it on the Vm:

> lsusb

shows me the dlink usb card

```
> lsmod
```

show me the rt73 module

```
>iwconfig, ifconfig, iwlist
```

shows nothing.

I tried many solutions found on Google and forums as compiling drivers, getting `ndiswrapper`, `ndisgtk`. `ndiswrapper -l` shows me my driver with the ID of the device but when I enter `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper` I got:

```
FATAL:Module ndiswrapper not found.
```

and still no wifi on my Ubuntu.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When I run Ubuntu 13.10 on my Toshiba L55 with an RTL-8188EE it works fine, however when I started it in VMWare the wireless card did not appear to be found.

The solution that worked for me was to go in to the VMWare Settings for Network, and change Adapter 1 to Bridged Adapter instead of NAT.  I then saw the Wireless adapter, said OK to save the changes and it worked fine after that

Hope that helps.